# parseInt on currency field returns NaN

Tags: php, javascript

I have a dynamic table in php/mysql that I show/hide columns by checkbox. The snippet of code below is part of the javascript that hides and recalculates the cells values for a total column.

```
function toggleVis(button) { 
// Toggle column 
cells = $$('.t'+button.name); 
cells.invoke(button.checked ? 'show' : 'hide'); 

// Recaulculate total 
$$('tr.row').each(function(row) { 
// Initialise to zero 
var total = 0; 
row.down('.total').textContent = total; 

// Sum all visible cells 
row.select('td').each(function(cell) { 
total += cell.visible() ? parseInt(cell.textContent, 10) : 0;
}); 

// Write the total in the total cell 
row.down('.total').textContent = total; 
}); 
}
```

This works great when the table content is simply numbers, but I now need to create another table with currency values in.  This causes the total column to return `NaN` presumably due the £ symbol. I format this in php with following code:

```
     <tbody>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_rsMISource['Source']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "£".number_format($row_rsMISource['May'], 2, '.', ','); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "£".number_format($row_rsMISource['Jun'], 2, '.', ','); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "£".number_format($row_rsMISource['Jul'], 2, '.', ','); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "£".number_format($row_rsMISource['Aug'], 2, '.', ','); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "£".number_format($row_rsMISource['Total'], 2, '.', ','); ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_rsMISource = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMISource)); ?>
    </tbody>
```

This outputs values such as £10,169.62, £7,053.00 or £.0.00

Is it possible to have the cells formatted with currency while still using the above posted js?

Comment: Could you please post the structure of the `td` elements generated by your PHP? JavaScript works on the HTML, the PHP script itself is largely irrelevant to JavaScript questions.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Have updated code to reflect the table structure & ouput..

Answer (score 5):

```
4 + '£4'; //NaN
4 + parseFloat('£4.3'.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '')); //8.3
```

That removes non-numeric characters from the string, and coerces the string to a number (so you get `8.3`, not `"44.3"`).

If you live in a country where the comma is used as the decimal separator rather than the period, replace `\.` with `,`

[EDIT - for your specific example:]

```
row.find('td').each(function() { 
    total += $(this).is(':visible') ? parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '')) : 0;
});
```

Quite a few code changes there.

Comment: Thanks @Utkanos, appreciate your input, as you may know I am lacking any JS knowledge, I tried adding total += cell.visible() ? parseFloat(cell.textContent.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '')); to my js code with no joy, is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: again many thanks for your kind help & time. I tried inserting the code into my js, the page runs fine but the total column no longer updates when  column is removed. Previously when I clicked to hide columns the totals column updates to sum only rows that are visible? Does that make sense?

Comment: Well I changed your `select()` for `find()` (since `select()` does not do what you perhaps thought it did). Can you set up a JSFiddle illustrating the problem?

Comment: Hi there, thanks again. Have placed code here http://jsfiddle.net/CvuxN/ doesnt quite work the same as my page but this is what it does; 1. User unchecks box 2nd Quarter, this hides columns May & June and then sums up the remaining rows. All works great until I format the cells in php to output £ currency? Thanks again

Comment: I had to add the cell values rather than pull from database, hence the currency formatting is removed too.